# How to get a decoded Play Integrity API token using the Google Client API for .NET

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to use the [Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1/latest/api/Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1.html) namespace of the Google Client API library for .NET to decode an integrity token, as recommended in the [Play Integrity API documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#decrypt-verify-google-servers).

However, it is unclear from the library documentation how to do this. It seems that the decoded token payload is supposed to be returned from a `DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse` object, yet I can't find any method that returns this type.

I would expect that this type would be returned from `DecodeIntegrityToken(DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest, String)` but this method actually returns another `DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest`, which doesn't help at all.

Is anyone successfully using this library to decode the token?

*References:*

- [DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1/latest/api/Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1.Data.DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse.html)
- [DecodeIntegrityToken(DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest, String)](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1/latest/api/Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1.V1Resource.html#Google_Apis_PlayIntegrity_v1_V1Resource_DecodeIntegrityToken_Google_Apis_PlayIntegrity_v1_Data_DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest_System_String_)

*Attempted Code:*

```
String integrityToken = "...token...";

String serviceAccountEmail = "...service account email...";

var certificate = new X509Certificate2("...key.p12...", "...secret...");

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
     new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
     {
             Scopes = new[] { PlayIntegrityService.Scope.Playintegrity }
     }.FromCertificate(certificate));

// Create the service.
var service = new PlayIntegrityService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Play Integrity API Sample",
});

DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest request = new     DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest();
request.IntegrityToken = integrityToken;
DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse response = service.V1.DecodeIntegrityToken(request, "...package name...");
```

> Error  CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1.V1Resource.DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest' to  'Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1.Data.DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rely on your ide to tell you what types these objects are

Your code says that the method `DecodeIntegrityToken` should return a `DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse`.  You are declaring it as such instead of using `var` and allowing the compiler to figure it out for you.

```
DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse response = service.V1.DecodeIntegrityToken(request, "...package name...");
```

Your problem is that this method actually returns a  `DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest`.

[image]

To get a `DecodeIntegrityTokenResponse`  you need to execute the request

```
var request = service.V1.DecodeIntegrityToken(requestBody, "...package name...");
var result = request.Execute();
```

*Full code cleanup*

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1;
using Google.Apis.PlayIntegrity.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");


var integrityToken = "...token...";

var serviceAccountEmail = "...service account email...";
var pathToCert = "...key.p12...";
var certPassword = "...secret...";
var packageName = "...package name...";

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(pathToCert, certPassword);

var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = new[] { PlayIntegrityService.Scope.Playintegrity }
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

// Create the service.
var service = new PlayIntegrityService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Play Integrity API Sample",
});

var requestBody = new DecodeIntegrityTokenRequest
{
    IntegrityToken = integrityToken
};
var request = service.V1.DecodeIntegrityToken(requestBody, packageName);

var result = request.Execute();
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it. If only executing the request were more obvious from the documentation :/

Comment: As far as i know im the only one writing documentation for this library, and i have never used this api so ‍♀️

Comment: @DaImTo Is it possible through the APK key method?Also can you please let me know from where we can get.pem file.

Comment: No idea about the api key but the p12 file comes from Google cloud console

Answer (score 0):

I have written a sample application to decrypt and verify the play integrity in C# using their own keys offline.

The official documentation doesn't have a C# code sample.

The sample application contains code for both .net framework and dotnet core.

Once you clone the applciation, search for //TODO and update with appropriate values.

[CSharp.PlayIntegrity.Decoder](https://github.com/rudreshgp/CSharp.PlayIntegrity.Decoder)

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the attestation statement locally in the following way.
I am using [Jose.jwt](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt) to make the code simpler here.

```
var decryptionKey = Convert.FromBase64String("<DECRYPTION KEY>");
var verificationKey = Convert.FromBase64String("<VERIFICATION KEY>");
var signedAttestationStatement = "<ATTESTATION STATEMENT>";

var ecDsa = ECDsa.Create();
ecDsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(verificationKey), out _);

var decrypted = Jose.JWT.Decode(signedAttestationStatement, decryptionKey);
var payload = Jose.JWT.Decode(decrypted, ecDsa);
```