# How to call DecodeIntegrityToken API

Tags: java, android

I'm stuck trying to call Google DecodeIntegrityToken API from my Android APP. There is no documentation or examples on how to do it.

I have completed the setup and managed to get an IntegrityToken up to this point.

The setup: https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict

[image]

Here I found calling the API in LARAVEL: [Decode integrity token using Google PlayIntegrity API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71526352/decode-integrity-token-using-google-playintegrity-api/71528749#71528749)

and this one in .NET: [How to get a decoded Play Integrity API token using the Google Client API for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72193083/how-to-get-a-decoded-play-integrity-api-token-using-the-google-client-api-for-n/72196786#72196786)

But how can I call it from Java? There is no information. I can't find a way to call the API to decode the Integrity Token.

Comment: As this post appears similar to [your prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72193058/295004) you should add detail as to what you've tried and where you are stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you can decode using Java based hosted service. The integrity token can be sent to the Google server from hosted service and you can verify the response received from google. Enable PlayIntegrity API in Google Cloud Platform against the app and download the JSON file and configure the code. Similarly, you should enable PlayIntegrity in Google PlayConsole

[Please check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72193058/google-playintegrity-api-a-nightmare/72461439#72461439)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for the node.js solution check my answer here

[Decode integrity token using Google PlayIntegrity API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71526352/decode-integrity-token-using-google-playintegrity-api/72566344#72566344)